# Xcode unable to run OpenGL code on macOS, MacBook Air, Catalina 10.15.3

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, opengl

I followed many websites which gives steps to run an OpenGl code, but still not working.

For OpenGl and glut, I tried header

```
GLUT/glut.h
OpenGL/gl.h
OpenGL/gl3.h
OpenGL/glu.h
OpenGL/OpenGL.h
```

but still says file not found.

I added OpenGl and GLUT framework and library, tried using different version of Xcode, tried using C Source and C++ Source, tried use terminal to run but showed a lot warnings. For Example:

```
main.cpp:26:9: warning: 'glutInitDisplayMode' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.9 - OpenGL API deprecated.
```

For GLFW, I followed "https://giovanni.codes/opengl-setup-in-macos/" to install GLFW through terminal, and finally Xcode shows some "Documentation Issues" "Empty paragraph passed to '@sa' command".

website said

```
/*
If you are in Catalina and run the project, your are going to see an error, that is because the library has not the permissions to run in your mac, so you will need to sign it to run.
In the terminal copy and paste the command
codesign -f -s "your@email.com" /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib
*/
```

and terminal shows `"error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain."`

Comment: The codesign command assumes you have purchased and installed a developer certificate with the specified email address, I assume you haven't done that. It shouldn't be necessary to sign code to run it on your own machine though, you might just need to give it permission to run from the settings/security dialog

Comment: Can you try starting from [Glitter](https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter) ? It is a CMake project but you can use it to generate XCode projects and Makefiles. That should sidestep any linking issues you have.